# No such File exception in Jenkins, but runs fine locally

Tags: java, jenkins

I have a JUnit test file for my code that reads an xml file and converts it to string:

```
String xml = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("src\\test\\resources\\testfile.xml")));
```

The test runs and passes locally, but when I run a Jenkins build, it fails with java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: src\test\resources\testfile.xml

Do I need to change my file path when pushing?

Comment: On what OS is your Jenkins server?

Comment: I believe its Linux. Also update: when I move the all the way out (same path as pom) and removed path spec from filename, Jenkins was able to build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I figured out my problem and I feel pretty silly. When Java builds on my windows machine, using \ to seperate files is fine; however when Jenkins builds, files need to be seperated with /

i.e. my file names should be

```
src/test/resources/testfile.xml
```

Comment: That's was the point of my question about the operating system.

Comment: And do not forget that Linux has a case-sensitive file system while Windows has a case-insensitive one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64277645/no-such-file-issue-when-running-jenkins-on-linux-server-but-its-working-when-jen

can help me to overcome this issue

Answer (score 0):

you should use resource as stream for this:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
if (is != null) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String xml = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
}
```

(code can be improved a lot ... but it will give you a direction)

(check out **try by resource** to handle streams)

Comment: This doesn't really address the issue: the problem is that Jenkins can't find the file based on the path.

Comment: It has to do with the file location .. the test resources folder will be packaged/moved so only the class loader can easily provide the access ... I work with that in my own projects aswell ... In IDEs it mostly is not a problem because the file is not packaged and at the location you expect. This cause the difference.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)

Comment: Check my above answer; that was the issue